# Mosh to a specific remote shell

Tags: ssh, mosh

With ssh, I can do something like the following:

```
ssh user@host -t /path/to/some/shell
```

How can I automatically launch a shell on the server with [`mosh`](https://mosh.mit.edu/)?

I have tried with

```
mosh user@host -ssh /path/to/some/shell
```

and with:

```
mosh user@host -ssh "ssh -t /path/to/some/shell"
```

with no luck. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
mosh user@host -- /path/to/some/shell
```

The general form is:

```
mosh [options] -- user@host [command]
```

If you don't specify a command, mosh spawn a login shell by default.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to pass commands as well? That is, e.g. doing  `ssh -t machine@domain 'export STARTUP_OPTION="A"; exec /path/to/zsh'` but with `mosh`  (see [this Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234393/passing-variable-definitions-to-specific-shells-in-ssh) for more context)

Comment: I tried with `mosh user@host -- "export LC_OPTION=A; /path/to/some/shell"` without luck.